# php checkbox value for sunday not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a weekly rota system using php and mysql. if a day is checked (using checkbox) the status is 'present' and if unchecked the status is 'day off'. it is working for mon-sat. but not sunday. it is producing 'day off; regardless of the checkbox is checked or not. Here is my code

```
**add.php**
<input type="hidden" name="mon" value="0" >
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" name="mon" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="tues" value="0" >
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" name="tues" value="2">
    ......
    ......
<input type="hidden" name="sat" value="0" >
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox6" name="sat" value="6">
<input type="hidden" name="sun" value="0" >
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox7" name="sun" value="7">
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


$day=date('w', strtotime($current_date));
         if( ($day==$mon AND $mon!=0) OR ($day==$tues AND $tues!=0) OR ($day==$wed AND $wed!=0) OR ($day==$thurs AND $thurs!=0) OR ($day==$fri AND $fri!=0) OR ($day==$sat AND $sat!=0) OR ($day==$sun AND $sun!=0)){
             $status='Present';}else{$status='Day off';}
```

Comment: If what you're trying to indicate is that your `if` condition is evaluating to `false` and thus invoking the `else` block then your next step is to debug and observe the values being used in that condition.  *When you debug* (using a step debugger, or failing that just outputting/logging values at runtime to observe them), what are the exact runtime values used in that `if` condition?  What was the observed result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: `date('w')` for Sunday is what? `0`. So how much sense does the condition `($day==$sun AND $sun!=0)` make then? The first part would only apply if $sun was 0 (because that's what $day is), but then `$sun!=0` can't be true at the same time.

Comment: Not sure how much sense this makes to begin with - your form can submit _multiple_ checked checkboxes, but it looks like you are only determining _one_ status value ...?

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for your help. I have made some adjustments and now it works. I have changed the checkbox values to Monday, Tuesday....Sunday. Also have changed the code to

```
    $mon=$row['mon'];
    $tues=$row['tues'];
    $wed=$row['wed'];
    $thurs=$row['thurs'];
    $fri=$row['fri'];
    $sat=$row['sat'];
    $sun=$row['sun'];
$day=date('l', strtotime($current_date));
        if ($day==$mon || $day==$tues || $day==$wed || $day==$thurs || $day==$fri || $day==$sat || $day==$sun)

{
 $status='Present';
        } else{
            $status='Day Off';}
```